# python sockets application not functioning as expected from terminal

Tags: python, linux, sockets

I'm following a book I purchased called 'Black Hat Python' but have run into an issue I cannot seem to resolve.

The book so far has had the reader create a few python applications: a command line tool to send/receive data, execute commands remotely and a TCP proxy client that redirects a connection via specified host/port.

The issue is that when I launch these from the terminal, I receive no output and the terminal waits for my input with a screen grab type cursor. It awaits for me to 'grab' an image or part of the screen 3 times and then fails. I then have some image files save to my Home folder named, 'getopt', 'socket', 'subprocess', 'threading' and 'sys'. The output I get from the terminal after 'grabbing' the screen 3 times is:

```
root@c0ff33:~# ./1proxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftpserver.ftp 21 True
./1proxy.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./1proxy.py: line 5: `def server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
```

However, when I run this in my IDE client, it runs fine when I pass it the same arguments. The connection is initiated and awaits the connection to the remote host. The output is then correct and the proxy client waits for a connection via localhost on port 21:

```
[*] Listening on 127.0.0.1:21
[==>] Receive incoming connection from 127.0.0.1:49475
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Why can I not execute this from the terminal with the same results?

The arguments I am passing are:

```
./myproxy.py 127.0.0.1 21 ftpserver.ftp 21 True

127.0.0.1 = localhost
21 = local port
ftpserver.ftp = remote host
21 = remote port
True = receive first
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That could happen because your shell tries to pass your script to BASH to execute. BASH will see lots of errors in your code. Instead of typing `./code.py` you need to run `python code.py` or add `#!/path/to/python` in the beginning of your script.

Comment: Again, instead of saying 'thank you', please consider accepting the answer. Thank you.